# The code is running but UPDATE command does not update data in the table

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, sql-update

I have to write the code which update a user's password. There must be entered a user's username (Brugernavn) , password (Adgangskode), new password and confirm password. The code is running, but UPDATE command does not update the password.

Until now, I have tried with this code (I know, that parametrized query should be used, but I don't have any idea about how to write such query, while this is combination of a SELECT and UPDATE statements):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS01;Initial Catalog=Vagtplan;Integrated Security=True");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Login_data WHERE Brugernavn='" + textBox1.Text + "' AND Adgangskode='" + textBox2.Text + "'", con);

        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        ErrorProvider errorProvider1 = new ErrorProvider();
        errorProvider1.Clear();

        if(dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
        {
            if(textBox3.Text == textBox4.Text)
            {
                SqlDataAdapter sda1 = new SqlDataAdapter("UPDATE dbo.Login_data SET Adgangskode='" + textBox3.Text + "' WHERE Brugernavn='" + textBox1.Text + "' AND Adgangskode='" + textBox2.Text + "'", con);
                MessageBox.Show("Adgangskoden er skiftet.", "Bekræftelse", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            }
            else
            {
                errorProvider1.SetError(textBox3, "Adgangskode passer ikke");
                errorProvider1.SetError(textBox4, "Adgangskode passer ikke");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            errorProvider1.SetError(textBox1, "Du har tastet forkert brugernavn");
            errorProvider1.SetError(textBox2, "Du har tastet forkert adgangskode");
        }

    }
```

The expected result is that password will be updated.

Comment: Never concat strings to make SQL queries.  Always use Parameters.  Never, ever store passwords as text - salt and hash them.  There is also no real reason to save the CONFIRM: it is an entry validation: if it doesnt match the other entry the code doesnt continue

Comment: Select *  is usually a bad idea. Is the PK in the update statement?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a SqlAdapter for your update statement, create a new SqlCommand as you do for the Select statement. Then call the ExecuteNonQuery method on the SqlCommand object.